# Inner Join MySQL Query Disregards 'WHERE' Clause?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I'm having a bit of trouble with a somewhat complex query, and I can't figure out what exactly is going wrong...

The query deals with two MySQL tables:

```
$userstable:
|| id || firstname || lastname
|| 1  || John      || Doe

$membershipstable:
|| groupid || templateid || userid ||
||   0     ||     1      ||    1   ||
||   1     ||     0      ||    2   ||
||   0     ||     2      ||    3   ||
```

Here is the query:

```
$query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        u.id,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname
    FROM $userstable AS u
    INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M1 ON u.id = M1.userid
    INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M2 ON M1.groupid = M2.groupid
    WHERE M2.templateid = :currenttemplateid
    ";
```

For reference, I have already double checked the variable for the placeholder`:currenttemplateid` and it returns correctly... What I am trying to do is return from the query only records for the current template's `id`, however the query returns the user data from the `$userstable` for any user associated with a template regardless of whether that template's `id` matches the current one specified in the `WHERE` clause.

If I've just completely newbd out on this one then I apologize, but I've been working with this code for a few hours now so my senses may not be as sharp as they should be... Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: For this sample data, what is your expected result?

Comment: For example, if the `$currenttemplateid` were say, "1", I would expect only the user data for the user with id "1" to be returned, as the user with `id -> 1` is associated with `templateid -> 1`. My current return is not only users associated with `templateid -> 1`, but also users that are associated with `templateid -> 2`.

Comment: I think you just need join `$membershipstable` with one time, what is your purpose of joining twice?

Comment: Essentially I need the query to:  1. select any user that has affiliation with the template 2. select any group that has any affiliation with the template, and for each group id found, look for any instance in the `$membershipstable` where that group id has affiliation with the current template. Then, for each user, and for each user in the group affiliated with the template, return their info from the `$userstable` table.

Comment: Use this only $query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        u.id,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname
    FROM $userstable AS u
    INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M1 ON u.id = M1.userid
    WHERE M1.templateid = :currenttemplateid
    ";

Comment: if previous query didn't satisfy your requirement then use $query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        u.id,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname
    FROM $userstable AS u
    INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M1 ON u.id = M1.userid
    INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M2 ON M1.groupid = M2.groupid and M1.templateid = M2.templateid
    WHERE M2.templateid = :currenttemplateid
    ";

Comment: First try both queries then i will explain you

Comment: @JohnDoe Your query seems to be no problem, check this:[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/35d09/2)

Comment: I ended up ditching the JOINS and created this ugly, but functional thing, perhaps it will better explain what I've been trying to do... `SELECT id, firstname, lastname, username, email FROM $usertable WHERE id IN (SELECT userid FROM $membershipstable WHERE templateid = :currenttemplateid or userid IN (SELECT userid FROM $membershipstable WHERE groupid IN (SELECT groupid FROM $membershipstable WHERE templateid = :currenttemplateid)))`

I'm not that good (obviously) with MySQL so these JOINS are just hurting my head...

Comment: did you tried this $query = " SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname FROM $userstable AS u INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M1 ON u.id = M1.userid INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M2 ON M1.groupid = M2.groupid and M1.templateid = M2.templateid WHERE M2.templateid = :currenttemplateid ";

Comment: I did, but it only returned users associated with the template directly, and not users associated to groups who are associated with the template...

Comment: Use this $query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        u.id,
        u.firstname,
        u.lastname
    FROM $userstable AS u
    INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M1 ON u.id = M1.userid
    INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M2 ON M1.groupid = M2.groupid and M2.templateid = :currenttemplateid
    ";

Comment: can you provide some sample data? Currently provided data is less to resolve

Comment: The last query you posted is the solution, thank you very much for being smarter than I. XD

Comment: ok, posting it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify Your Query As follows:-

```
$query = " SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.firstname, u.lastname 
           FROM $userstable AS u 
           INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M1 ON u.id = M1.userid 
           INNER JOIN $membershipstable AS M2 ON M1.groupid = M2.groupid and M2.templateid = :currenttemplateid ";
```